# error with Int function in Xcode 7 beta

Tags: swift

I have this error while I was testing the code in Xcode 7 beta, the error between the two asterisk

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var agee: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var labelAge: UILabel!
@IBAction func findAge(sender: AnyObject) {


    *var enteredAge = agee!.text.toInt()*

    if enteredAge != nil {

        var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

        labelAge.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

    } else {

        labelAge.text = "Please enter a number in the box"

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@IBOutlet var agee: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var labelAge: UILabel!
@IBAction func findAge(sender: AnyObject) {

    if agee != nil {

    var enteredAge = agee.text.toInt()
    var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

    labelAge.text = "Your cat age is \(catYears) in cat years"
    print(catYears) // Just check in the logs
    }
    else {
        labelAge.text = "Please enter a number in the box"
    }

}
```

Just paste the above code in your project.

Don't forget to connect those @IBOutlets and @IBAction again[ctrl+drag] in the assistant editor. Otherwise you'll stuck in a signal issue(SIGABRT) 
Hope it helps!

Comment: This does not explain the problem and would not compile with Xcode 7.

Comment: Try this var enteredAge = agee!.Int(.text). If not post a screenshot. So that I can understand the exact error